# Only site administrators should be able to set default display view of folders on Plone 4.3

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

All logged-in members of my plone site have the permission to edit, create and publish content. Unfortunately, they are also able to change the default display view of a folder. This leads to a lot of problems as the site members sometimes - accidentically - change to a view template that a folder is not suitable for.

How can I change plone the way that only role administrator is able to set the default view of all folders? Normal site members should not be able.

Since I trust my members something like a JS+CSS solution that hides the display menu for everybody except site administrators would be acceptable, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The permission you are looking for is called `Modify view template`. All roles with this permission can change the template. If your Workflow manages the permission, give it only to the Administrators.

If your Workflow does not manage the permission you can change it globally by change the security configuration on the plone root.

Goto: `http://plonesite/manage_access` (Security-tab in ZMI)

Search for `Modify view template`.

Change the configuration. In your case only allow `Administrator` to change the view template.